# Track changes removed using xml is not working with document.close in .net

Tags: .net, openxml

I am using a utility to remove the track formatting from the word document. It is working fine if I am not using document.close. Below is the method which i am using

```
private static void RemoveTrackChangesFormattingFromTheDocument(ref WordprocessingDocument   document)
{
  Program.AcceptAll(document);//this method will remove all the format changes
  //it is working fine if i will not use
  document.close();
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your `AcceptAll` method is using `using`, e.g.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
    WordprocessingDocument.Open("DocumentWithRevisions.docx", true))
{
    RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions(doc);
}
```

and so `.Close` is called automatically as soon as the closing brace is reached?

For reference: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-content/blob/master/en-us/OpenXMLCon/articles/b3406fcc-f10b-4075-a18f-116400f35faf.md#open-the-existing-document-for-editing